# How to to get maximum sequence number in SQL

Tags: sql

This is the data I have in my table. What I want is maximum sequence number for each order number.

```
Order No seq    Sta
--------------------
32100     1     rd
32100     3     rd
23600     1     rd
23600     6     rd
```

I want to get the following result without using cursor.

Output:

```
Order No seq  Sta
-----------------
32100     3   rd
23600     6   rd
```

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to to add a tag for the database engine you're using (MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server, DB2, Oracle, ...)

Comment: Which database engine are you using?

Comment: Is `Sta` unique per `Order No`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most simple solution is using `group by` with `max`.

Give this a try:

```
select [Order No], max(seq), Sta
from myTable
group by [Order No]
```

Comment: This won't work on most RDBMSes . `Sta` has no agg function and it isn't in group by.

Comment: @Gowdam . . . It is sad that you accepted an answer that is not standard SQL, works in few databases, and promotes bad programming practices.

Answer (score 3):

If you want entire records you could use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Order ORDER BY No_Seq DESC) AS rn
      FROM tab) s
WHERE rn = 1;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=646907d743cddb1f9533cee7b4fff194)**

Please do not use keywords like `Order` and spaces in column names.

Answer (score 0):

Just use group by order no and order by sequence desc and you will get your record.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **Oracle** Database then you can use **ROW_NUMBER()** analytical function to achieve this result

Try the below query:

```
select 
    * 
from
    (select 
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY order_no ORDER BY seq DESC) as "ROW_NUM", 
         order_no, seq, sta
     from 
         Order_Details) temp 
where 
    temp.row_num = 1 ;
```

**[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/af5a9/5/0)**

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably the most efficient solution in most databases (with the right index):

```
select t.*
from t
where t.seq = (select max(t2.seq) from t t2 where t2.orderno = t.orderno);
```

You can also do this with `group by`:

```
select orderno, max(seq), sta
from t
group by orderno, sta;
```

Note that all columns referenced in the `select` are either `group by` keys or arguments to aggregation functions.  This is proper SQL.